# jquery setting width to a variable value

Tags: jquery

Could someone explain what's wrong with this snippet?

I'm looking to get the width of all images in a div.

```
var totalwidth = $("#imagecontainer > img").width();
$("#imagecontainer").width(totalwidth);
```

sorry, thought it was just a syntax problem
(un)working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/TZ2nT/3/
the container div does not accept the value for some reason?

Comment: The snippet doesn't look to be wrong at all? What is your context of the question?

Comment: Syntactically, nothing. Without more information (markup, specific error, etc) all we can do is guess.

Comment: You may be interested in the CSS solution `display: inline-block` to make the DIV wrap to your image. That way, if people don't have Javascript enabled, it degrades peacefully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

did u tried this

```
var width = $("#imagecontainer  img:first").width();
var totalWidth = width * $("#imagecontainer  img").length;
console.log(totalWidth);
```

**Edit** :

```
$(function() {
  var totalwidth = 0;
  var arey = [];
  $('#imagecontainer img').each(function() {
    var width = $(this).width();
    width = parseInt(width);
    arey.push(width);
  });

  for(var i in arey) {
   totalwidth +=arey[i];
  }
  $('#imagecontainer').width(totalwidth);
  $('#readout').html(totalwidth);
});
```

Test it here **http://jsbin.com/ayira3**

Comment: Wow thanks. I know this is not what I asked for but it's what I was looking for. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really described what is wrong, but I'm guessing you're running the code *before* the image has been fully downloaded, so it doesn't yet have a width.

If that's the case, try this:

```
$("#imagecontainer > img").load(function() {
    var $th = $(this);
    $th.parent().width( $th.width() );
});
```

Remember that [jQuery's `.ready()` method](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) does *not* wait for images to load. You can use [the `load()` method](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) agains the `<img>` element instead. This way the code will not run until you actually have an image.

If you ever need to run code after *all* images have loaded, you can use:

```
$(window).load(function() {...
```

Comment: thanks but i can get and pass the value elsewhere though (see example), so i don't think that's the problem.

Comment: @jack - In the example you posted, the imagecontainer is getting the width. So what is it not doing for you?

Comment: I modified your example slightly and it's working for me. http://jsfiddle.net/TZ2nT/4/ outputs `782 vs 782` for me.

Comment: @jack if want to cache the total width of the images, you need to sum up the individual width. `$("#imagecontainer > img").width();` this won't give you the total width

Comment: ah how stupid, i wanted the width of all the images, didn't notice that the value was only for one image! thanks for pointing this out.